# Fullcalendar Events not displaying before 9 o'clock

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I'm using the `jQuery` plugin `Fullcalendar` so far I was able to display the data stored in my `MySQL`  Database but it is not displaying the right way. What I mean is:

e.g.:

```
}
    "id":"1","title":"Test",
    "start":"2015-01-28 10:30:00",
    "end":"2015-02-04 12:30:00",
    "url":"",
    "allDay":"false"
}
```

This is one record in my Database. It is supposed to display on my calendar

`2015-01-28 10:30:00`   to  `2015-02-04 12:30:00`.

But it's not. Instead `allDay` is `true`(even if in the database it say `false`) and I need to add an other day too.

e.g.: If I want to display the dates from 16-03 to 17-03, I need to add an other day -> 16-03 to 18-03 (so that it displays 16-03 to 17-03).

What I mean is when I put a record after 9 o'clock the event "box" or `div` extends to the right date. Other wise it doesn't extend to the right date.

But by default `businessHours` are `false`. (I even added : `businessHours: false`) but no success.

This is my `SELECT` query:

```
<?php
$json = array();

// Query that retrieves events
$querySQL = "SELECT * FROM evenement";
// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbcontrol", "root", "");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$result = $bdd->query($querySQL) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
    echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

And this is my `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: currentTime,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,

            eventBackgroundColor: '#A80000',
            eventBorderColor: '#A80000',

            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: './php/select-events.php',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: I guess, start & end format is not correct..check fullcalendar manual and try to adjust it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem -> `"allDay":"false"`

`allDay` should have a boolean value, not the string "false". Changing it to `"allDay":false` will make it work.

Comment: it generates another issue by showing a prefix '12a' before the title text on full calendar.